# android samsung note 2 unsync gmail and other accounts

Tags: gmail, google-account, samsung, accounts

My phone was stolen and I want to unsync my gmail and other associated accounts in it. Is there a way for me to do that even if my phone is not with me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change your password online.

Comment: Related: [How to prepare in the event of stolen phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34635/how-to-prepare-myself-smartphone-tablet-in-the-event-it-goes-missing-or-is-sto/34640#34640)