# Realistic preparations to be made beforehand to locate the device and/or ascertain identity of its holder?

Tags: lost-phone

What can and should be done beforehand as a precautionary measure to locate the device or ascertain the identity of its holder, should a person unknowingly lose his/her device for any reason?

I am thinking of ways which provides features, such as:

- keeping camera turned on nonstop upload data as much as possible to possibly capture holder's face and location along the way, or
- perhaps prevent the phone from being turned off and create a loud sound "THIEFS" in the middle of crowded bus

If the solutions requires app, I would prefer such apps which can't be turned off.

Also, perhaps something we can put on our keychain that will cry out loud if the distance between the Android device and the keychain is above 1 meter.

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: I found one good solution. Cobra Tag. But it's not available anymore.

Comment: Hi! Your edit was still focused towards explicitly demand of apps to achieve objective. As you've witnessed based on closure reason, anything that asks us to look for apps or device is off-topic here. But note that if the problem does require an app you would get it as an answer. Just make sure you don't directly mention your demand for an app or so in question since direct demands causes quite a SPAM here. They also make the question obsolete a bit more quickly. // I've edited and tried to make it as much on-topic I can. I can't guarantee though that it won't be considered too-broad now.

Comment: It appears that we already have a question along the same lines: [How to prepare myself & smartphone/tablet in the event it goes missing or is stolen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34635)